# Google Chrome doesn't follow image redirect

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, http, facebook-graph-api

I have to insert to HTML page image from facebook graph, for instance this one: http://graph.facebook.com/100004504487972/picture?type=large. In fact this link returns `307 Internal redirect`.

I'm inserting this image with simple HTML img tag:

```
<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/100004504487972/picture?type=large" />
```

In most browsers it works well, but chrome for some reason doesn't follow redirect.

You can try this jsbin in different browsers to check out:

https://jsbin.com/yuhoqanisi/edit?html,output

I'm testing in latest chrome under ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact it happen to be Ghostery extension for Chrome blocking image.